# assign a variable z as the number of factors of 2 in the number stored in variable x

Tags: java

I come across this problem and I have now clue what to do.
This is my semester taking programming class.
So, I have to write a code that assign z as the number of factors of 2 based on whatever number stored in variable x.

For example, if x = 64, then z = 6 because it store number of factor of 2 based on the number of x.
(Since  64 = 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 x 2. (there are 6 numbers of value "2")
Another example, if x = 48, then z = 4 because x = 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 x 3)

Any clue on how to do this? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: What about showing us what you have done so far ? We wont make your homework for you and cant help without a code issue.

Comment: divide X by 2 and then divide the result by 2 and so on and count how often this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = 0;
while (x % 2 == 0) {
        x = x / 2;
        i++;

}
```

i keeps a record of the number of times you have already divided by 2 and when the loop is finished will be the number of times x will divide (eg in your example it is 6 and then 4). The loop will keep iterating until WHILE x is divisible by 2. "i" will be the number at the end that will be the number of 2's in your answer, ie what you call z.

Comment: Thank you Steven. Your code gives me and idea how to write it. Since I just set value z as number of counter, and it will show me the factor of 2 of whatever number x was.

Answer (score 0):

I got it guys...

here is the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class bull
{
    public static void main ( String [] args )
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner ( System.in );

        System.out.print ( "Enter four digit numbers: " );//prompt the user to enter numbers

        int x = input.nextInt();//read number entered by user
        int counter = 0;
        int z = counter;

        while (x % 2 == 0)
        {
             x = x / 2;
               counter++;
        }

  System.out.printf( "The factor of 2 of the x values are %d\n", counter );

     }
}
```